# Android getExtra receive only first parameter

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass two parameters of array from first activity to second using intent and putExtra get Extra, but second activity shows only the first parameter:

sending activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewContact.class);

            intent.putExtra("Name",MyContacts[i].getName());
            intent.putExtra("Phone",MyContacts[i].getPhone());

            startActivity(intent);
```

receiving activity

```
TextView nameview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_view);

    TextView phoneview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone_view);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


    String name  = extras.getString("Name");

    nameview.setText(name);


    String phone  = extras.getString("Phone");
   phoneview.setText(phone);
```

the result: receiving activity shows only nameview

Comment: Are you sure `MyContacts[i].getPhone()` isn't null or empty when you send it? Is it really a `String`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I tried to put "Phone" in first getString and then it shows only the phone

Comment: Sounds like your `phone_view` `TextView` isn't visible. What's your layout XML look like?

Comment: Remove the setText() code from receiving activity and put some values in your layout xml for your both the TextViews and check whether those are visible. If they aren't then the issue is with your layout xml.

Comment: You are right guys, There was a problem with layout. Thanks a lot